# Old references never die

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I'm able to run an asp.net application using a console host to host my services.  This works fine.
When I install the services to a server and then attempt to access them with my application, I get an error when running my search function (it's a search application)  I used to be doing it using a stored procedure that is dynamically created which was using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll to create a sql server object and create a stored procedure.  Now I'm doing it without a stored procedure and so I no longer need this reference.  However, when I try to run my search function with the services installed on the server, it keeps failing because it can't find this file.  I've emptied all my bin and obj directories, cleaned the services solution and the asp.net application solution, but it keeps looking for this reference.

I even searched my computer for this file and it was only found in its original location (C:\Program Files\MicrosoftSqlServer\100\SDK\Assemblies).  I don't know what else to do to tell my program I no longer care about this reference.

Please help if you can!  Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Is this a *web application* or *web site* solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assembly may still be referenced in your `web.config` file.

Answer (score 2):

Did you remove the reference to that DLL in your References?